# Detect local storage changes and show on page without reloading

Tags: angular, local-storage, ionic4

I have an issue with angular,ionic 4 localstorage.When i save data on localstorage from one page ,and want to show the data to an other page,i need to reload the page to make it work.I thought about checking for localstorage changes in the page i want to show the data.Do you know how can i detect changes in localstorage in angular 7,ionic 4?

Comment: have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use rxjs stream to accomplish this.

```
   private storageSub= new Subject<string>();
  ...

  watchStorage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.storageSub.asObservable();
  }

  setItem(key: string, data: any) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, data);
    this.storageSub.next('added');
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    this.storageSub.next('removed');
  }
```

Comment: i get this error :Argument of type '"changed"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean' from here:this.storageSub.next('changed');

Comment: Ah sorry, of course it will error. If type is boolean you should then pass a true false. Its up to you how will you find this more appropriate. I think you should just change to new Subject<string>();

Comment: It works! i did as you said in my dataService and i call watchstorage on my home page.In home i am getting the values from the storage and placing them to a chart like this :: this.storage.get(this.Uid).then((val) => {.....}

do i have to put it inside this to work?? ::     this.dataService.watchStorage().subscribe((data: string) => { if(data=='changed'){
  this.storage.get(this.Uid).then((val) => {.....}
} });

or would i reload the window if the if statment is true?

Comment: You dont have to reload. You are on the right way. (this.dataService.watchStorage().subscribe((data: string) =>...) Subscribe and watch the stream and act based on the "data". Do anything if the statement is true.  Please dont forget to upvote or mark this as your answer :)) Enjoy your stream :)

Comment: Ofc .Thanks alot mate!!

Comment: may i ask one last question.I tried calling this.dataService.watchStorage from 2 pages.But it called only from one do you know why this happens?
@Adapttoweb

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly. You have isolated the observable in a service I guess. Do you get any error? Can it be that you forgot to add it to the module or did not import it to the second page properly? Normally, services can be used in multiple page/components.

Comment: So.I have 3 tabs(Home,Profile,Settings) and some other pages.I include the observable in Home and Profile tab.When i make a change to localstorage from one of my pages it works perfectly on home page but not in profile page.But here is the Issue.When i call my dataServiceDelete() function from my Settings page the observable is called from profile page.I use console.log to get the information.I hope you understand what im talking about.

Comment: I think the Observable should be in the service. And all the pages can use it. If I am not understanding correclty. Please try to provide me with similar situation on StackBlitz and will try to help

Comment: This does not do what the OP asks at all.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a value in the `storage` has changed you can add a `listener` to the `event of the storage` like this:

```
document.addEventListener('storage', (e) => {  
    if(e.key === 'theyKeyYouWant') {
       // Do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can have a service which takes care of setting and retrieving values to/from localStorage in property setters and getters.

Once the template is bound to properties, your respective components will be updated on change detections.

For example, this is your service with one property you want to set in localStorage.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SetStorageService {

  private _localItem: string = '';
  constructor() { }

  set localItem(value: string) {
    this._localItem = value;
    localStorage.setItem('localItem', value);
  }

  get localItem() {
    return this._localItem = localStorage.getItem('localItem')
  }

}
```

And your components like:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  private _item: string = ""

  constructor(private _storageService: SetStorageService) {}

  set item(value) {
    this._item = value;
    this._storageService.localItem = value;
  }

  get item() {
    return this._item = this._storageService.localItem;
  }

  addValue() {
    this.item = "New Value"
  }
}
```

Your view will be bound to the property which is ultimately getting its data from localStorage (through the service).

```
<p>
  Item in App component - <b>{{item}}</b> 
</p>
```

See an example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgdz8e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score -2):

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

To remove you can use

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    localStorage.removeItem('key');
  }
```